# How to redirect to a page after printing with primefaces Printer?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have used the primefaces printer and wanted to redirect to previous page after printing.I used Printer like this:

```
   <p:commandButton  value="Print" type="button" title="Print" actionListener="#{currentpage.redirect}"> 
        <f:ajax execute="@this"/>
        <p:printer target="printer" />
    </p:commandButton>
```

In redirect method of currentpage bean i deleted the record which works fine but if i try to redirect it to previous page it doesn't do anything.

```
public void redirect(ActionEvent actionevent) {
              /* Deleted the record */ 
}
```

Please guide me if i can do this way or anyother way.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several misconceptions in your code:

- `actionListener` method **can not** fire a redirect. That could be done in `action`
- An ajax request **cannot fire** a redirect. Ajax is meant to work as an asynchronous request to the server and get the desired result to the current view and handle the response to update the view without refreshing the page nor without navigating.
- If using Primefaces components, you should work with them for efficiency in your page. For example, `<p:commandButton>` should work with `<p:ajax>` rather than `<f:ajax>`. But in this case, `<p:commandButton>` already has ajax capabilities built-in, so there's no need to use any of these ajax components.

After knowing this, you know that your design should change to this:

```
<p:commandButton value="Print" type="button" title="Print"
    action="#{currentpage.redirect}" process="@this">
    <p:printer target="printer" />
</p:commandButton>
```

And the method declaration to:

```
//parameterless
public void redirect() {
    /* Deleted the record */ 
}
```

PrimeFaces let's you add behavior when the ajax request is complete by usage of `oncomplete` attribute. This attribute receives the name of a javascript function that will be invoked right when the ajax request finishes without problems. In this method, you can add the logic for your redirection:

```
<p:commandButton value="Print" type="button" title="Print"
    action="#{currentpage.redirect}" process="@this" oncomplete="redirect()">
    <p:printer target="printer" />
</p:commandButton>

<script type="text/javascript>
    redirect = function() {
        window.location.href = '<desired url>';
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Tried this but action and oncomplete both are not working now.

Comment: @niks please do not say *it's not working*, explain what's the problem you have.

Comment: The issue i'm having is it doesn't go in the redirect function in currentpage bean and nor it goes to javascript fuction.It only prints when clicked on the button.In other words no record get's deleted as well as it does not redirects to some page,it only printer is working on button click.

Comment: this is my issue as I mentioned above.Does it make sense?